# Hiding base class or interface from polluting code

Tags: c#

this is an issue ive been faced with countless number of times.. consider..

```
[public/private] interface IBase
{
    void DoCore();
}

public interface IDerived_A : IBase
{
    void Do_A();
}
public interface IDerived_B : IBase
{
    void Do_B();
}
```

here i have 2 useful interfaces that provide some common functionality (provided by the IBase interface), plus some other functionality unique to either of them.. c# forces me to declare IBase as public (the same visibility as the inheriting interfaces).. however, the IBase interface is visible to everyone.. there is no need for anyone else to use this interface.. ppl only need to access the IDeriver_X interfaces.. how can i hide the IBase interface from the users of my code? there can be two kinds of users of my code..

1. code in the same namespace / assembly accessing IDerived_X..
2. code in a separate project referencing the assembly containing IDeriver_X..

ps.. i hate making more interfaces public than is neccessary (neccessary means only those interfaces that ppl will use directly)..
ps2.. i face the same dilemma with classes..

EDIT:

i have a feeling that the question was misinterpreted a bit.. for that im posting a clarification.. the issue isnt just related to interfaces.. it bugs me about classes too.. consider the following code..

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    // generic vehicle functionality
}
public Car : Vehicle
{
    // functionality specific to cars
}
public Truck : Vehicle
{
    // functionality specific to trucks
}
```

Car and Truck are the ONLY two kinds of objects im allowing the users of my code to use.. to make my job easier, and to avoid dupilcation of code, ive moved the common code to the Vehicle abstract class.. but that doesnt mean its ok for the user to store references to cars or trucks in vehicle variables.. from the perspective of the users, my code should only expose cars and trucks (and not vehicles or engines or whatever base classes i used internally to avoid code duplication).. specifically, im looking for a technique that allows me to expose complete cars and trucks but not any other incomplete building blocks like vehicles or engines.. the problem is, c# doesnt let me make the base classes private if the derived class is public.. does that make more sense? =)

Comment: If `IDerived_A` and `IDerived_B` are designed to be public what is the harm in making their base interface `IBase` public? The implementer of those interfaces will need to implement `IBase` as well. Why are people not using `IBase` directly?

Comment: If there is no need for anyone to use `IBase` then it follows that an `IDerived_C` will never exist. In which case why not use `IDerived_A` and `IDerived_B` directly (e.g. overload a method to accept either)? I wouldn't actually do that, but if you absolutely must make `IBase` diseappear...

Comment: @Jon.. yes thats the point.. IDerived_C will never exist unless ive created it myself.. the user is NOT going to create any new derivations.. she will only use what ive provided.. yes i can delete IBase and copy its functions/fields to both IDerived_A and B.. but it duplicates code.. even more so if we're talking about classes instead of interfaces.. why is c# forcing me to reveal to the user of my code what classes ive used to make a particular class?

Comment: yes i can use encapsulation instead of inheritance to hide the inner interface / class but it still forces duplication of code.. writing `void DoSomething() { InnerObj.DoSomething(); }` in every one of the encapsulating classes / interfaces..

Comment: i wanna know if there's a way that i can expose only a particular class / interface down the heirarchy level without exposing ALL the parent interfaces / classes to the user as well..

Answer (score 3):

Well,

- either it makes sense that your child interfaces are derived from a base
- or user of child interfaces should not have access to API of a base

In first case, it is reasonable, that consumer of API IDerived_A has access to IBase. 
In the second do not dervie from the base IBase

Anything else, is tweating OOP.

As a consumer of your interface, I am provided with both IBase and IDerived_A, so it is reasonable that I do have access to IBase

Comment: You are not 'provided with both IBase and IDerived_A', you *must* implement all methods from IDerived_A contract. If you also have access to IBase - you can potentially avoid this *must*. That is the point of OP's question i guess.

Comment: Once the IDerived_A is derrived from IBase, I do have access to all IBase properties and methods. That is the principal of the OOP!

Comment: Consider you are implementing Controls hierarchy. Then other developers will be creating new controls deriving from your base interfaces/classes. But you *want* that they implement all methods from most derived interfaces, but they can potentially (by mistake for example) derive from one of the base interfaces. So they avoid implementation of some important methods.

Comment: Well that is solved in OOP, very well. DO not derive your IDervied interface from IBase. Just implement the IDerved and IBase separately. No inheritance. Then you can even profit from explicit implemetation in C# (in comparison with Java) BUT do not derive from anything, if you do not want me to have access to the base!

Comment: Yes, this is one of the options for this scenario. But it will produce code duplicate ;)

Comment: @SergeyS.. this is exactly the issue.. please see the edit in the opening question for an example scenario.. its not just limited to interfaces.. classes too.. i wanna give the user two objects to work with.. why should i give away everything i used to make up those objects? i used inheritance to avoid duplicate code.. but it handicaps me by forcing me to expose the entire inheritance chain to the user.. theryby allowing the user to create entirely new types of objects..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to express here(so maybe a description of your complete scenario may help).
If your `IDerived_A` and `IDerived_B` interfaces ARE `IBase`s, your client code needs to be able to access `DoCore`. And having `IBase` public would allow you to generalize functionality that works the same on types inheriting either `IDerived_A` or `IDerived_B`.

If you just want to avoid repeating method definitions in `IDerived_A` and `I_Derived_B` but inheritance from your `IBase` is NOT modelling a IS A relationship (i.e. I_Derived_A and I_Derived_B don't need to be directly related in a hierarchy but are just sharing some functionality between them) you should probably just create separate interfaces with no hierarchical relation between them, like this:

```
public interface ICore 
{
    void DoCore()
}

public interface INonCore_A // no more inheritance
{
    void Do_A();
}

public interface INonCore_B 
{
    void Do_B();
}
```

now the classes in your library code can be requested to implement both `ICore` and `INonCore_A/B`. `ICore` itself may still need to be public (unless you want the DoCore method itself to be only visible to your library code) but you can sort of "hide" it in your classes by using an explicit interface implementation of `ICore`.

What you lose, in this second case, is a way to tell your client code that implementing `INonCore_A` **requires** you to also implement `ICore`.
That functionality exists for instance in the scala programming language but not in C#. If it existed you could say:

```
// warning: non-existing c# syntax. Does not compile
    public interface INonCore_A {
        self: ICore => // this is scala syntax, does not work in c#
                       // it means "anyone who implements INonCore_A must 
                       // also implement ICore
            void Do_A();
    }
```

As said, since this does not work in c#, it is down to documentation and programmer's discipline to make sure that whoever implements `INonCore_A` and B also implements `ICore`